# Symfony 4.1 - sonata admin - overide template for single showmapper item

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm trying to override single template of show action like this:

```
public function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
    {
        $showMapper
            ->add('smsShipments',null, array(
                'template' => 'sms_shipment_list.html.twig'
            ))    
    }
```

but I'm getting a warning like this:

> An error occured trying to load the template
>   "sms_shipment_list.html.twig" for the field "smsShipments", the
>   default template "@SonataAdmin/CRUD/base_show_field.html.twig" was
>   used instead.

And error consequently like this:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "An exception has been
>   thrown during the rendering of a template ("Warning: nl2br() expects
>   parameter 1 to be string, object given")." at
>   C:\xampp_7\htdocs\project_name\vendor\sonata-project\admin-bundle\src\Resources\views\CRUD\base_show_field.html.twig
>   line 23

This works great in Symfony 3.1.
Could you provide an alternative solution to override show element or show action for single admin?

Comment: So, please show us your template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulling from this [SonataAdminBundle guide on the official Symfony 4.x documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/action_show.html#customising-the-query-used-to-show-the-object-from-within-your-admin-class), I see that you'll need to have your twig template in `templates/Namespace/sms_shipment_list.html.twig`.

Then, then refer to it in the options argument as `@App/Namespace/sms_shipment_list.html.twig`.

Something like this, then:

```
public function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{
    $showMapper
        ->add('smsShipments',null, array(
            'template' => '@App/Namespace/sms_shipment_list.html.twig'
        ))    
}
```